# How to passing value from link in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

My link in view page

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url('baju_c/cari/'.$hasil->id)?>" class="btn btn-default">Detail</a>
```

My controller

```
public function cari(){
    //what i'm doing here ? please help ?
}
```

My model

```
function search_by_id($id){
        $query = $this->db->where('id',$id);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
    }
```

How pass value from link to model and show the result to view again?

it's my first time using codeigniter, need some help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your controller ,receive the value passed through link by uri class.And then pass it into your model.

Controller :

```
public function cari()
{
  $id= $this->uri->segment(3);
  $this->model_name->search_by_id($id);
}
```

[Take a look on this.](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/uri.html)

Answer (score 2):

You have to pass argument into method:

```
public function cari($hasil_id){
    if ((int)$hasil_id > 0)
    {
        $this->load->model('Name_of_model');
        $data['search_by_id'] = $this->Name_of_model->search_by_id($hasil_id);
        $this->load->view('hasil_view', $data);//assuming page for item
    }
    else
    {
        redirect('not_good_id_method', 'refresh');//in case of not valid id
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer

Comment: My pleasure to help. If it solves your issue feel free to [accept it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work#answer-5235) allowing others with similar problem to pick working solution.